# How to know all the resources, connections, sockets, etc. in use by a Node child-process on Linux

Tags: mysql, linux, node.js, sockets, child-process

I generate a node script dynamically, then fork a child process through node to execute it and pass the output back to the parent process

In parent:

```
  //...build child.js
  var child  = require('child_process');
  childProcess = child.fork('child.js');
  childProcess.on('message', 
       function(dataFromChild) { 
         //process data 
   });
```

In child process

```
process.send(objectToSend,function() {
 //code to send objectToSend
 //process.exit(0);
}
```

The actual code is a lot more extensive.  I also use socket.io and mysql. I think I am closing all opened db connections and sockets in the child process when I am done processing. However, the child process does not exit. If I do a process.exit(0) at the point of exit, it does exit. I figure there must be something that it is open that is not allowing it to exit naturally. How do I know what it is?

I have tried a simple child script, basically a one-liner with a console.log statement to test if it will exit without an exit statement. It does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the linux `lsof` program to list all open file descriptors owned by the child process. In node, the [active-handles](https://www.npmjs.com/package/active-handles) npm package should help you track down allocated listeners, timeouts, etc.

Comment: The lsof is useful indeed for debugging. Upvoted. Now, among the "files" which are in use by that specific process, which are the ones that possibly prevents it from exiting? I see some unix sockets, no TCP sockets and I do not expect any. My goal is to exit naturally not through a forced process.exit(0)

Comment: Did you run active-handles? Can you post the output in your question?

Comment: I will run active-handles. I have never used it before. Let me install and see... probably get it done later today. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Gave it a quick try.  I don't know if I am doing it right but `activeHandles.print();` just where I expect the program to exit, gives this as the first line `onread: net.js:501:15 (net client connection, fd = 11)`
This is followed by some code. If you think that is going to help, I can post the code.  But the first line seems to tell me that there is a socket open? Is that it?

Comment: Yup so something is leaving a network data handler bound it seems. If there's a connection pool to a DB for example, make sure the pool is fully closing all its connections, not just the active one.

Comment: I have enough directions received from you to research forward. Was in the dark. I am accepting your answer. I think that it might precisely be what you said... db pool while I am closing just one connection.